# Pagination Code

Tags: javascript, php, pagination

I am just beginner in php and I am finding difficulty in the pagination code. According to my client he needs a pagination on top and as well in bottom. So for that I have written this code like in below : which the code states I have totally 8 pages to display and each page has 12 records. It will work in inline display till 8 pages but that looks odd. So my management said to do in this format `<< < 1 2 3 4  > >>` and each time the page changes the next number should be displayed but it display only till 4 pages after that it doesn't show the next page.

```
<?php
$limit = 12;
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products WHERE type='1'";  
$rs_result = mysql_query($sql);  
$row = mysql_fetch_row($rs_result);  
$total_records = $row[0];  
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit);
?>
<div align="center">
<ul class='pagination text-center' id="pagination">

<?php if(!empty($total_pages)):for ($i=1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++): 
        if($i == 1):?>
         <li class="page-item">
  <a class="page-link" href="granite.php?page=<?php echo $i;?>" aria-label="Previous">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
</li>
        <li class='current'  id="<?php echo $i;?>"><a href='granite.php?page=<?php echo $i;?>'><?php echo $i;?></a></li> 
        <?php else:?>
        <li id="<?php echo $i;?>"><a href='granite.php?page=<?php echo $i;?>'><?php echo $i;?></a></li>

    <?php endif;?>        
<?php endfor;endif;?> 
<li class="page-item">
    <a class="page-link" href="granite.php?page=<?php echo $i;?>" aria-label="Next">
     <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
     <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
          </div>
```

And i have written this javascript code for changing the pagination like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//Loading Image Display
function Display_Load()
{
  $("#loading").fadeIn(100);
  $("#loading").html("<img src='loading.gif' />");
}
 //Hide Loading Image
 function Hide_Load()
{
 $("#loading").fadeOut('slow');
};


 //Default Starting Page Results

 $("#pagination li:first").css({'color' : '#FF0084','border' : 'none'});
 $("#content").load("granite.php?page=1", Hide_Load());

  //Pagination Click
  $("#pagination li").click(function(){
  Display_Load();

  //CSS Styles
  $("#pagination li")
  .css({'border' : 'solid #dddddd 1px'})
  .css({'color' : '#0063DC'});

  $(this)
  .css({'color' : '#FF0084'})
  .css({'border' : 'none'});

  //Loading Data
  var pageNum = this.id;
  $("#content").load("granite.php?page=" + pageNum, Hide_Load());
   });
 });
```

Please can anyone help me where I am doing wrong and give me the guidelines to correct it.

Comment: "It's not working" is not a very good description of the problem. More info needed.

Comment: #bert I have given more info about the problem what I am facing.

Comment: There is no pagination there. You have no `limit` in your query, and no way to select what 'page' to display. the `?php=foo` you pass as a query argument to the script is NEVER used.